# Editing contacts creates a duplicate

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

I have 5 different email accounts: iCloud, GMail, Hotmail and two others which my iPhone does not give the option to sync its contacts.

So, I have only synced my contacts with iCloud and since barely a month ago, when I edit a contact it appears immediately a copy of it and if I delete one, both of the are deleted.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score -1):

Does the duplicate appear on your iPhone or within your iCloud account.

Try editing your iPhone contacts directly via this tool for example:

http://www.copytrans.net/iphone-contacts.php

Also, where do you edit the contact entries from which the duplicates result - on your iPhone or within the iCloud. I would assume that if you are editing them on the iPhone, a temporary local copy is created on your iPhone until it is synced back to the iCloud after which the duplicate copy (physically residing on your iPhone) will be gone.